# Why to calculate base voltage in given example differently?

Tags: circuit-analysis, bjt

[image]

In this problem as we can see base voltage is 3 V (simple voltage divider)

But in other problem but goes under saturation, but here in solution they didn't use voltage divider and use other approach
Taking base voltage as Vb and then emitter voltage Vb+0.7 and collector voltage as Vb+0.7
Here answer comes is different then previous case Vb.[image]
So here my question is why can't we can't attack this question with voltage divider? Why have to take different approach? Why answer is different than previous one?

Comment: In the second example the BJT is in the saturation region, hence \$I_C = \beta * I_C\$ don't hold anymore. So we cannot ignore the base current in the calculation. Because now in saturation the base current can heavily loaded the voltage divider, so the voltage divider output voltage is no longer equal to 3V.

Comment: ...and we should not forget that the voltage VB=3V in the first circuit is only an approximation! Even in this case (BJT not n the saturation mode) there is a (small) base current which was neglected for calculation of the voltage divider. In fact, it is a loaded divider.

Comment: The 1st approach is valid and best for both cases due to ratio of Ic to base bias string << hFE i.e. Rb(eq)/Rc ratio. << hFE   ...l ... a) Vce= 1.7V b) Vce=0.1V approx. to 220 mV max with rCE<=80 Ohms and to get 0.1V assume Ic=(12-0.1-8.3)/7k= 0.5 mA and Ie=Ic+Ib =1mA then Ic/Ib <<10. where 10 is a safe minimum , satisfies my assumption. That's my 5 minute analysis of which 4 minutes is peek and poke typing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Active region of operation which is first case value of β is very high, in case of high value of β base current is almost zero, it makes 9k and 3k in series and it is convenient to use voltage divider.

But in saturation region which is second case value of β will decrease, so the base current will not almost zero in this situation. So we can not use voltage divider as 3k and 9k is not in series any more so we have to take approach of Thevenin theorem.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the divider in ***all*** cases of analysis. The following schematic illustrates the Thevenin equivalency:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fR5FU6.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

This Thevenin equivalence always works and it never fails. There aren't any tea leaves you need to read to figure out when a divider somehow isn't a divider in one case but is a divider in another. You can always replace the divider, as shown above, whether the transistor is saturated or isn't saturated. It's all the same thing.

Now, you can easily prepare the following equation using Kirchhoff's laws and then solve for \$I_B\$. Treating all terminal currents in \$Q_1\$ as positive and also treating a forward-biased base-emitter junction voltage as positive:

$$\begin{align*}
V_{TH}+I_B\cdot R_{TH}+V_{BE}+I_B\cdot\left(\beta+1\right)\cdot R_1&=V_{CC}
\\\\
\therefore I_B&=\frac{V_{CC}-V_{TH}-V_{BE}}{R_{TH}+\left(\beta+1\right)\cdot R_1}
\end{align*}$$

Of course, normally you can just plug in a reasonable estimate for \$\beta\$ and be done with it. From there, you can work out \$I_C=\beta\cdot I_B\$ and \$I_E=\left(\beta+1\right)\cdot I_B\$.

But what if you can't rely on the assumption of some a priori estimated value (or bracketed range of values) for \$\beta\$? Well, there's another Kirchhoff's law equation you can write down here, and solve it for \$V_{CE}\$:

$$\begin{align*}
0\:\textrm{V}+I_B\cdot\beta\cdot R_3+V_{CE}+I_B\cdot\left(\beta+1\right)\cdot R_1&=V_{CC}
\\\\
\therefore V_{CE}&=V_{CC}-I_B\cdot\left(\beta\cdot R_3+\left(\beta+1\right)\cdot R_1\right)
\end{align*}$$

Now, just plug in the equation for \$I_B\$ into that equation to get:

$$\begin{align*}
V_{CE}&=V_{CC}-\big[V_{CC}-V_{TH}-V_{BE}\big]\cdot\frac{\beta\cdot R_3+\left(\beta+1\right)\cdot R_1}{R_{TH}+\left(\beta+1\right)\cdot R_1}
\end{align*}$$

If \$\vert V_{CE}\vert \ge \vert V_{BE}\vert\$, then your estimated \$\beta\$ value appears to work okay and this means that \$\beta\$ is an input and that \$V_{CE}\$ is an output of the above pair of equations.

But if not, then you know the opposite is true: That \$V_{CE}\$ is an input (or bracketed range of inputs) to the pair of equations (roughly, it's an estimated saturated value) and then \$\beta\$ is an output you need to solve. In this case, perhaps set \$V_{CE}\approx 300\:\textrm{mV}\pm 200\:\textrm{mV}\$ and solve for \$\beta\$:

$$\begin{align*}
\beta&=\frac{R_{TH}\cdot\left( V_{CC} - V_{CE}\right) + R_1\cdot\left( V_{TH} + V_{BE} - V_{CE}\right) }{ R_3\cdot \left(V_{CC} - V_{BE} - V_{TH}\right) - R_1\cdot\left( V_{TH} + V_{BE} - V_{CE}\right)}
\end{align*}$$

Here, you will find the required low value for \$\beta\$ in order for the circuit to work at the given saturation level for \$V_{CE}\$.

But in all cases, your voltage divider concept remains workable. The issue is simply whether or not \$\beta\$ can be treated as constant (active, not saturated) or \$V_{CE}\$ is to be treated as nearly constant (in shallow or deep saturation.)

---

In your first case, assume \$\beta=200\$ and \$R_3=2\:\textrm{k}\Omega\$. Then you compute \$I_B=4.968\:\mu\textrm{A}\$ and \$V_{CE}\approx 1.724\:\textrm{V}\$. That looks like it is in active mode. So that's fine. So \$I_C\approx 994\:\mu\textrm{A}\$ and \$I_E\approx 999\:\mu\textrm{A}\$.

In your second case, assume \$\beta=200\$ and \$R_3=7\:\textrm{k}\Omega\$. The equation for \$I_B\$ doesn't care about the change in \$R_3\$, so we get the same \$I_B=4.968\:\mu\textrm{A}\$, again. But this time, \$V_{CE}\approx -3.245\:\textrm{V}\$. That tells you that it cannot be in active mode. So now you let go of \$\beta\$ and instead (let's say) choose \$V_{CE}=200\:\textrm{mV}\$. Now, using the last equation above, you get \$\beta\approx 1.914\$.

So that is your saturation \$\beta\$ and the circuit is saturated. Take that value for \$\beta\$ and go back and plug it into the first equation to compute \$I_B\approx 314\:\mu\textrm{A}\$ and \$I_C\approx 601\:\mu\textrm{A}\$ and \$I_E\approx 915\:\mu\textrm{A}\$.

---

Bottom line? The divider is still a divider. It still has a Thevenin equivalent. All is right with the world. The only question you really need to resolve is if \$\beta\$ may be treated as a constant or if \$V_{CE}\$ may be treated as a constant.

---

Final note: I wanted to include 3 places of significance in the calculations above so that the quantitative results from entering these expressions correctly can be verified. That is my entire intent in providing that level of precision -- a way of cross-checking the algebra.

I do not, in any way, mean to imply that the resulting quantities will be anywhere near as accurate given actual parts. All of the inputs to these calculations are, at best, approximate. The value of \$\beta\$, assuming that the BJT is in an active region, will vary significantly from part to part. So will the \$V_{BE}\$ for each part. The same is true for any estimation of the saturated \$V_{CE}\$, if the transistor is saturated.

For a practical design, reasonable variations in supply rails, variations around nominal resistor values, and BJT variations around \$V_{BE}\$ and forward \$\beta\$ values should be bracketed during the analysis and then verified by similar runs using Spice to help cross-check those estimates. This was not done here as this is just a question about "what happened to the divider?" Which can be addressed without having to be side-tracked into yet another chapter on a different (important) topic.

Comment: can you truncate sigfigs in future please to reflect tolerances. in 2nd case , data-sheet says Vce(sat)=-0.25V MAX at Ic=10mA and Ic/Ib=10 why do you est. Vce(sat) is 300+\-200mV?

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75 I could, but I actually wanted to include 3 significant places BY FULL INTENT here because I wanted the OP (and/or anyone learning from this) to try out their own calculations and I wanted to provide enough detail that they can verify, themselves, that they are plugging into the right quantitative expressions. It was intentional. If this were a design for a practical circuit that I knew was to be built, I'd have done what you recommend at the outset. But I agree, of course, that there is no precision on the inputs to these equations.

Comment: agreed 4 digits get good error checking on calculations. but 300mV+/-200mV is not in datasheet. Did you see my simpler way?

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75 I added a note to my answer to accommodate your comments here.

Comment: Do you ever guess at  Vce(sat) vs Ic? or as I do estimate  rCE from datasheet then compute it.

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75 I want to (1) encourage quantitative algebraic analysis using the basic Kirchhoff laws; and, (2) show a simple idea -- that either \$\beta\$ is "constant" or else \$V_{CE}\$ is "constant" -- which permits a final algebraic solution using that basic process.

Comment: yes but as you know, β  is never  "constant" with a 3:1 range best case unless binned and 10%~20% β when saturated.   Comments on rCE?

Comment: I agree your algebraic method is beautiful but I prefer my shortcuts and rely more on datasheet tolerances and compute rCE or ESR vs I

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75 I completely sympathize with the need for shortcuts. I use them myself and *do not* use the approach I show here, above, in practice. Probably for the same reasons you don't. But again, I just want to address the OP's question (about the divider) and what I perceive as an issue about ***quantitative analysis using basic laws***, showing how one can approach the result in that fashion. Doing things the "hard way" once or twice is IMPORTANT in order to deepen those shortcuts and to understand their LIMITATIONS, as well.

Comment: agreed but it is important to also stress the Ic/Ib ratio in switch or saturated mode and understand why this drives ESR or rCE of Vce/ Ic ratio

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75 I'm not convinced that was the OP's question. I think I saw, already, in other questions the OP asked that such "rules of thumb" aren't the desire. Even if so, there are some who may benefit from this approach, so as to thoroughly fathom why saturation \$beta\$ is an ***outcome*** of other circuit factors rather than an ***input*** to them. One might, incorrectly, imagine that \$\beta=10\$ is some kind of important magic number that "just works." Sadly, that's not the case and it should never be treated that way. It is, instead, the accidental outcome of other factors.

Comment: No I insist hFE should be set to 10% of linear region hFE vs Ic and rCE used to compute Vce(sat) vs Ic.  Ic/Ib=10 is just a de facto standard for Vce(sat) for datasheets. This is far more accurate than any other method when good specs are avail, from OEM.   The Op should understand his 2nd analysis assumes Vce=0 which is rarely the case, but close enuf for "government work" I assumed Vce=0.1V with some rCE internal bulk resistance.